# How to calculate gradients in ResNet architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I assume that somehow the gradient at each layer will be 0.1. The gradient of a paint/stack network a layer can compute by accumulating the gradient as 
[image]

In the ResNet, the gradient is propagated by skip connection. So, how can I achieve the gradient of `x` as above figure? Is it `0.1x0.1+0.1` or `0.1`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Have added the gradient calculation in the above diagram. The gradient `delta_x` is the sum of the incoming gradient `delta_y` and the product of the gradients `delta_y` and `delta_F`.

So in your example, it should be 0.1x0.1x0.1+0.1.

But note that the in actual calculation of `delta_F`, the `delta_y` gets multiplied by `weight_1` and gets `passed/blocked` depending on whether `ReLu` is active and then gets multiplied by the `weights_2`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.